# XCode - How can I set a top margin to a Table View Cell?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, tableview

I'm using a Custom Table View Cell to create an app but I need to set its top margin, so I can repeat the cell (by using a for) and setting a top. https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdVlC.png

However, I don't know how to set it, I've tried with `topAnchor` but it requires a `NSLayoutYAxisAnchor` and I don't have that.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Set the top inset

Comment: AutoLayout is your friend when you are using a Nib - https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use a UI view  in your cell and set a top margin between your cell and view

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Vishal. I have already found the way to get it work. So I'm using a TableView in a UIViewController instead.